# How much should I charge to backup a NAS drive to my server every night?

Tags: information-technology

How much should I charge my client to backup the data from a Synology NAS drive to my home Windows server which is used as a FTP server for backups? I don't want to seem expensive or charge too little as this is a new sector for me.

The backups will happen every night at a specific time and be incremental backups, but I don't think they have a lot of data, possibly looking at around 300GB below. These will also happen automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Does your client care about their data and the ability to recover it and do they care about making sure that it's secured in transit and at rest? Do you care about doing what's in your clients best interests? If the answer to both questions is yes then find them a solution that doesn't involve transmitting their data to your home server and storing it there.

Answer (score 0):

My advice is as follows:

1. Ensure you have backups of your server as well
2. Ensure the customer does NOT have access to PUSH the backups to your server
3. Invoice monthly for total storage used
4. Ensure there is a signed contract detailing what you are backing up, and on what schedule, along with instructions for the client to receive their data as requested
5. Ensure you are completely covered!

With doing backups of any type, you should strive to do PULL backups - your backup system should reach out to the servers it needs to backup, and grab the files that way. If you have a PUSH system, then it is as effective as a USB drive plugged into their server. Ransomware could potentially find it, the keys/passwords could be exposed to other staff, etc.

Ensure you have versioning setup, even if it uses slightly more space. I have had customers ask for data from a couple weeks ago, and a couple months ago. Having that data saved them a lot of headache.

Assuming you have the space and time to set it up, it could be a great money maker for you. Ensure you offer an encrypted connection, since FTP is not encrypted in any form.